# Angular : Failed to load images: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, css, json, bootstrap-4

i download [this free theme](https://github.com/BootstrapDash/PurpleAdmin-Free-Admin-Template?) in order to use it in my angular project in WebStorm but i get this error :
 `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
                                                                                     and no image is loaded even if the path is right. can anyone help me with that?

here is a snippet of the code:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo"/></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo-mini" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-mini.svg" alt="logo"/></a>
```

**[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLimX.jpg)**

**[Directory tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkhLr.jpg)**

**PS:** i did have problems with loading CSS and JavaScript files but i'v already solved them by adding type="text/html" in css links and type="application/json" in JavaScript links. do you think it can be a JSON problem?

Comment: How is your code, show some code of when you are loading those not found images.

Comment: @CassianoMontanari i'v edited my question with some code

Comment: use /images/logo-mini.svg, the app folder is your root folder, so start with /

Comment: are you sure images have been downloaded? check in browser's network tab?

Comment: Cannot GET /images/dashboard/img_4.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by placing images into `assets` folder of Angular. Previously I placed them into `app` folder and had 404 error too, but placing into `assets` solved my issue. So I use them like:

```html
<img src="assets/images/intro_room.jpg" alt="Intro Gallery Room Sample Pictures">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try starting your image source link with `/` like `/images/logo.svg`

Comment: can you try: ```../images/logo.svg```?

Comment: @chimchim can you try that?

Comment: there is no change :(

Answer (score 1):

When a folder i.e. images and `index.html` file are in same directory, then the path should start with `./`

```
<img src="./images/logo-mini.svg" alt="logo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the route in angular.json in architect > build > options > assets:

`"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/images"]`

After this you have to stop it and relaunch you app.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here: You have to add the route in angular.json in architect > build > options > assets:

"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/images"]

After this you have to stop it and relaunch you app.

from Ivan Gomez is likely the true right answer.  This worked 100% for me.  The real reason the image directory did not work was that angular did not have it registered as an asset driectory.  Adding the image to the asset folder is also correct, but if you want your own image folder to hold images you need to add it to the angular.json file as Ivan directs.

Comment: Awesome.  I tried everything else, but this is what solved the problem for me.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really have in assets directory, but try to put all static files like css and images into assets directory.

Comment: it's a bootstrap 4 theme and there is no assets folder. you can check the directory structure from the link in the question.